# Change all unique country abbreviations to country names and place in one cell

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula

I need a formula that can add all the countries with that is in a column.

Example:
In sheet 'Export' I have the below countries of origin:

[image]

And in other sheet I need to show all the countries of origin and change the name from RO to Romania or SK to Slovakia, etc...

What I have until now is the formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE, IF(left(Export!Q1,2) = "RO" , "ROMANIA", IF(left(Export!Q1,2) = "US" , "USA", IF(left(Export!Q1,2) = "PT" , "PORTUGALIA", IF(left(Export!Q1,2) = "FR" , "FRANTA", IF(LEFT(Export!Q1,2) = "SK" , "SLOVACIA"))))))
```

But is not working. It only shows the first country found, not all of them.

Can anyone help?

Link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-Iz0K-tKKjuur6eF3tvEiEJP6zLjm8tAl0RXZqOwX9M/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Welcome. Please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Comment: Your sheet is an .xlsx file. Please convert it to a Google sheet and then **share that link**.

Comment: link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-Iz0K-tKKjuur6eF3tvEiEJP6zLjm8tAl0RXZqOwX9M/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT** (following OP's request)

> And If I want it to show only one time the country? To summarize all
> of them and to appear only one time.
>
> Like this " Romania , Slovakia , England " in one cell. The purpose is
> to search in column Q if is that country and if it is, then write it.
> I need to be written only one time, one country. From on sheet, column
> Q, what countries are they.

*"To show only one time the country"* use

```
=ArrayFormula(UNIQUE(IFERROR( 
           SWITCH(Export!Q1:Q, "RO", "Romania", 
                                "SL", "Slovakia", 
                                "EU", "European Union",
                                "GB", "England"))))
```

To show "Like this `Romania , Slovakia , England` **in one cell**" try

```
=ArrayFormula(JOIN(", ",UNIQUE(QUERY(IFERROR( 
           SWITCH(Export!Q1:Q, "RO", "Romania", 
                                "SL", "Slovakia", 
                                "EU", "European Union",
                                "GB", "England")), "where Col1 is not null"))))
```

---

So what you want is to change the country abbreviations from `RO`, `SK`, `EU`, `GB` to `Romania`, `Slovenia`, `European Union`, `England` etc.

Please use the following formula.

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR( 
           SWITCH(Export!Q1:Q, "RO", "Romania", 
                                "SL", "Slovakia", 
                                "EU", "European Union",
                                "GB", "England")))
```

[image]

*(Do adjust the ranges and following the pattern provided add more countries according to your needs)*

Functions used:

- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`IFERROR`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304)
- [`SWITCH`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013690)

Comment: Welcome. Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Answer (score 0):

And If I want it to show only one time the country? To summarize all of them and to appear only one time.

Like this " Romania , Slovakia , England " in one cell.
The purpose is to search in column Q if is that country and if it is, then write it. I need to be written only one time, one country. From on sheet, column Q, what countries are they.